# ZFS on Linux: Can ZFS send a snapshot and receive a newer snapshot of the same dataset at the same time?

Tags: linux, zfs, snapshot

I have a production server `P` and a standby server `S`. Both are running Debian buster and **OpenZFS / ZoL** 2.1.0. `P` has only internal disks which provide ZFS storage for the O/S, the VMs and all other data. `S` has the same internal disks, but also has one additional backup disk which contains a separate ZPOOL, can be hot-swapped (hardware-wise), and serves as backup disk which is regularly rotated.

On `P`, there is only one pool, called `rpool`. On `S`, there are two pools: `rpool` (as on P), plus `extpool` (on the backup disk).

On `P`, a script runs regularly which takes snapshots of the ZFS datasets and replicates them to `S` via `zfs send` / `zfs receive`. On `S`, a script runs regularly which replicates snapshots from `rpool` to `extpool` (also via `zfs send` / `zfs receive`). The scripts on `P` and `S` are not synchronized yet, meaning that the script on `P` might try to replicate a snapshot to `S` while the script on `S` is in the process of transferring a snapshot from `rpool` to `extpool`.

From time to time, the script on `P` fails when trying to send the snapshot. I believe that this happens in the situation described above, so I suspect it is just not possible to send a snapshot of a dataset and at the same time receive a newer snapshot of the same dataset. On the other hand, chances are that I am doing wrong something else, so I'd like to be sure in this respect. In other words, I'd like to know whether it is at all possible to do the following:

On `P`:

```
zfs snapshot rpool/dataset1@snapshot1
zfs send -R rpool/dataset1@snapshot1 | ssh S 'zfs receive -F rpool/dataset1'
# Wait some time
zfs snapshot rpool/dataset1@snapshot2
```

and then **at the same time**

On `S`:

```
zfs send -R rpool/dataset1@snapshot1 | zfs receive -F extpool/dataset1
```

and on `P`:

```
zfs send -R -I rpool/dataset1@snapshot1 rpool/dataset1@snapshot2 | ssh S 'zfs receive -F rpool/dataset1'
```

As a final note, and to clarify: On `S`, none of the datasets which are involved in replication are ever mounted. The only thing `S` does with those datasets is receiving new snapshots from `P`, storing them on the internal disks, and in turn replicating all snapshots from the internal disks to the external backup disk.

The only exception of course is the emergency case: If `P` fails, the replicated datasets will manually be mounted on `S` and switched to production operation there. The question I have asked explicitly does not relate to this situation, though.

Comment: Do the snapshots have the same name on both servers (e.g. just @snapshot1)? or are they unique per server (e.g. @S-snapshot1 and @R-snapshot1)?  I don't imagine good things are going to come from trying to overwrite an existing snapshot with one that has the same name but different data.

Comment: as for the timing issue, check to see if zfs receive is already running and exit if it is (e.g. `zfs send ... | ssh S 'pgrep -af zfs.receive >/dev/null && exit 1; zfs receive ...'`).  The sender side should run the `zfs send` in a while loop and keep trying again every 30 or 60 seconds or so.

Comment: or, it may be that just ensuring that the snapshots have unique per-host names will eliminate the timing problem.    But you're still probably going to have problems if any programs have any **open** files on the dataset when a zfs receive overwrites the dataset.  so try to avoid that.

Comment: @cas At first, thanks for caring! Yes, the snapshots of course have the same names on both servers; plus, the series of snapshots is 100% identical, except for the snapshots which have not been replicated yet from P to S. Regarding the timing / synchronization: I'll probably have to implement a sort of synchronization (I guess I know how to do that), but that actually was my question: Can I get away without it?

Comment: @cas Unfortunately, per-host snapshot names won't solve the problem: P replicates to S's internal disks, S replicates from its internal to external disks, and the question is whether this is possible without synchronization. Files being open on replicated datasets on S cannot happen, because the O/S system of S is on a separate dataset which is not involved in replication. The datasets being replicated to S and then to the external disk are not used for anything else than replication. Notably, they are not mounted anywhere (except in case of emergency of course); in fact, they are ZVOLs.

Comment: I thought you were trying to merge snapshots from two servers into one server.  Wrong.  So the data gets sent from P:rpool/dataset to S:rpool/dataset, and then from S:rpool/dataset to  S:extpool/dataset?   That should be easy:  the script/cron job that does the send from S:rpool/dataset  to S:extpool/dataset should just wait until there are no `zfs receive` processes running.  e.g. using `pgrep` as in my example above.   It should check for `zfs.receive` AND `zfs.recv` as either may be used interchangeably.  `pgrep -af zfs.rec` should catch both.

Comment: BTW, there's no reason why you can't send and receive from a pool at the same time.  the problem you're encountering is, I believe, that the snapshot you're trying to send from S:rpool to S:extpool doesn't actually exist until S has *finished* receiving it from P.  If it doesn't exist, you can't send it.

Comment: Yes, exactly: P -> S internal -> S external. The scripts on P and S are independent so far. That is, P regularly creates a new snapshot and incrementally sends it to S, and that's the *only* thing P does. Independently from that, the script on S checks which snapshots *already exist* on S's internal disks, and replicates those of them to the external backup disk which don't exist there yet. I guess I'll have to do some more basic tests to identify the problem :-)